# RawRabbit - How to publish/subscribe to JSON message

Tags: json, rawrabbit

I'm trying to do few quick prototypes of using RabbitMQ as message broker for internal services as well as messages from external clients received by gateway over websocket connection.

I decided it would be best (and probabaly only) option for client to publish messages as json, and then for gateway to simply send the unaltered json messages forward.

I've seen that RawRabbit have the ability to take raw Json as message and then deserialize it to C# class.

What I can't find is some example and/or documentation of how the process should look like. Also cannot find documentation of how the Json message should be formatted.